# How To Remove Bite Order Mark in Facebook Links

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, byte-order-mark

When I post a picture in Facebook and add a (short) link, it attaches a bite order mark to them which sometimes brakes them.

Example:
https://www.facebook.com/LookrLookouts/photos/a.209741922569950.1073741827.154207248123418/338205879723553/?type=1&theater

[image]

---

If you copy the link URL, you see that the link actually points to http://lookr.com/1236334672%EF%BB%BF - which is wrong!

---

**What do I need to do that FB does not change the links and leaves them as they are?**

*PS: Anyone else having these problems?*

Comment: Does this happen every time? Is it limited to photo posts? Does it only happen when the link is at the end of the message? (And, are you sure that this BOM was not probably contained in what you pasted into the Facebook message field already …?)

Comment: Looking at this via Graph API Explorer, it looks like this text is actually the name given to the photo, correct?

Comment: @CBroe Yes, this text is the comment/description of a picture post.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, this happens everytime. No, it happens also if I post a regular text message without an image. No, it happens also if the link is not at the end of the message.

Comment: Does it happen if your text include `'http://'`? Looks like you're posting a text and Facebook detect it as link. I would suggest you to [report it](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/).

Comment: @amudi Actually, the link shows up correctly if I also include the `http://` - I filed a bug/problem report.